# Combine 3 disks in one case but keep separate drives

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, nas

I've got 3 external USB3 Casings each with a Sata600 3.5inch disk. These are connected to an Odroid XU4 for my NAS solution.

Is there a way to limit the amount of casings and cabling by one casing but still see each drive as separate?

3 power adapters, 3USB cables and the Odroid itself takes up a lot of space.

I've seen (RAID)Boxes but they are either overpriced or a RAID-solution.
Does this device even exist? 
Or should is a dock a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right before me: JBOD (Just a Bunch Of Disks): the individual disks are presented (to a server) with no amalgamation, pooling or structure applied.

So that means I should find a RAID-box with a JBOD-modi.